# Search / Filter posts on Title/Content OR Tags

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, wp-query, query

I need to make a custom query to look for posts (CPT) which match a certain keyword but it have to search posts in both the title, the content AND a custom taxonomy terms.

I’ve tried with to queries but I just can’t get it to work and I’ve of cause made sure that there are content in wordpress which match the criteria.

For clarification I’ll just explain the use case.

I got a CPT called **products**

The CPT has a custom taxonomy called **details**

There are approximately 100 details which all has a name and a description. The **products** itself also have a title, a description (the content) and some other fields.

At the product page, I want to have a “filter” function (Not the regular Wordpress search function!).

So if I filter the products by the keyword **cool** then it should query the CPT **products** and find the products which contains the word **cool** in either its title, its content or if it is marked with a taxonomy term which contains **cool** in it’s title / description.

My two queries I’ve tried looks like this:

**Query 1:**

```
//the $s variable is for testing only
$s = 'cool';

$query = "SELECT $wpdb->posts.* FROM $wpdb->posts
INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
WHERE $wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE '%$s%'
OR $wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '%$s%'
OR $wpdb->terms.name LIKE '%$s%')

AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = ‘details’
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = ‘products’
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = ‘publish’
GROUP BY $wpdb->posts.ID
ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC";
```

**Query 2:**

```
//the $s variable is for testing only
$s = 'cool';

$query="
SELECT $wpdb->posts.*
FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->term_relationships, $wpdb->term_taxonomy, $wpdb->terms
WHERE ($wpdb->terms.name LIKE '%$s%'
OR $wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE '%$s%'
OR $wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '%$s%')

AND $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id
AND $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type 'products'
ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
```

I’ve also tried to log Wordpress’ own queries to find out how it queries a keyword filtering with a specific taxonomy selected but I haven’t been able to transfer it proper to my own code.

I hope someone can help me and any help or advice is very much appreciated.

Cheers,
- M

Answer (score 1):

I worked it out myself..

The query I was looking goes like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM $wpdb->posts, $wpdb->term_relationships, $wpdb->term_taxonomy, $wpdb->terms
WHERE ($wpdb->terms.name LIKE '%$s%'
OR $wpdb->terms.slug LIKE '%$s%'
OR $wpdb->posts.post_content LIKE '%$s%'
OR $wpdb->posts.post_title LIKE '%$s%')
AND $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id
AND $wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id
AND $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id
AND $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish'
AND $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'products'
ORDER BY $wpdb->posts.post_date DESC
```

Cheers,
- M